# Open file shortcut safari developer tools

Tags: safari, google-chrome-devtools, safari-web-inspector

I use CMD + P to open a file directly in Google Chrome Developer tools.  Is there a shortcut to do this in Safari developer tools?  Currently I'm just scrolling through individual files and clicking :(

Comment: Anyone have an answer for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately Apple hasn't picked up on the usefulness of this yet.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/KeyboardShortcuts/KeyboardShortcuts.html

Comment: Outdated answer

Answer (score 11):

Just end ed up here today. A quick update to say that there is now a shortcut: `Command-Shift-O` (cf. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/safari-developer/keyboard-shortcuts-reference-dev654e5967f/11.0/mac/10.13)

Comment: This is the correct answer!!!! I couldn't debug React just because I couldn't find the files. Only this works, thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

`Command`+`P` now works perfectly fine in Safari as well.